# Radians value went wrong for CGAffineTransformRotate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, rotation, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to rotate the bicycle wheels when I rotate the pedal.

When I rotate counterclockwise, there is no problem.

But when I rotate clockwise for about 2-3 secs, the image starts to rotate counterclockwise instead with fast speed.

When I tried to log the angleInRadians value:
angleInRadians value varied from -0.05 to -0.1 at most when rotating counterclockwise.
angleInRadians value will be in between 0.05 to 0.1 at the start but suddenly the value change to -6.1, -6.2 something like that. See the log below.

I changed the anchor point of the image. I'm not sure this will matter or not.

Sorry for my bad english and formatting

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.PedalTurn.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.6);
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.PedalTurn.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.PedalTurn.bounds));
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.PedalTurn];
    CGPoint previousPoint = [touch previousLocationInView:self.PedalTurn];
    CGFloat angleInRadians = atan2f(currentPoint.y - center.y, currentPoint.x - center.x) - atan2f(previousPoint.y - center.y, previousPoint.x - center.x);
    self.PedalTurn.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.PedalTurn.transform, angleInRadians);
}

Angle in radians: 0.110071
Angle in radians: 0.0984247
Angle in radians: 0.107355
Angle in radians: 0.118767
Angle in radians: 0.121201
Angle in radians: 0.112823
Angle in radians: 0.0899732
Angle in radians: 0.0883234
Angle in radians: 0.105448
Angle in radians: 0.0884745
Angle in radians: 0.0983613
Angle in radians: 0.108684
Angle in radians: 0.119307
Angle in radians: 0.108768
Angle in radians: 0.111302
Angle in radians: 0.145414
Angle in radians: -6.14848
Angle in radians: -6.13048
Angle in radians: -6.12109
Angle in radians: -6.14578
Angle in radians: -6.13917
Angle in radians: -6.11675
Angle in radians: -6.13025
Angle in radians: -6.15015
Angle in radians: -6.14989
Angle in radians: -6.15097
Angle in radians: -6.14732
Angle in radians: -6.15547
Angle in radians: -6.136
Angle in radians: -6.13241
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions:

1. `atan2f` will return +pi or -pi for calls like `atan2f(+-0, x)` when `x < 0` so you could have an issue where both `currentPoint.y` and `previousPoint.y` are "equal" to `center.y` but you're getting a `+0` in one case and a `-0` in the other case, so instead of getting a difference of `0` you get something like -pi - (+pi) ~ -6.28.  If that's happening then you might want to handle the cases where `currentPoint.y == center.y` and `previousPoint.y == center.y` specially, even if that means just calling `atan2f` with a literal 0.0 instead of doing the arithmetic.
2. My other suggestion is that you don't iteratively determine the transform at all.  Why bother with `CGAffineTransformRotate(self.PedalTurn.transform,…` and doing arithmetic with the previous and current positions?  Just use the current position and make your rotation like this:

   `self.PedalTurn.transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(atan2f(currentPoint.y - center.y, currentPoint.x - center.x));`

   Then you don't have to worry about your arithmetic getting wonky as you go through multiple iterations.

Comment: The second method worked perfectly fine with a little modification

Comment: self.PedalTurn.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.PedalTurn.transform, atan2f(currentPoint.y - center.y, currentPoint.x - center.x));

CGAffineTransformMakeRotation works weird in my condition.
Thank you Aaron.

By the way, I tried you first suggestion and it didn't work.

    if (currentPoint.y == center.y && previousPoint.y == center.y)
   angleInRadians = atan2f(0, 0) - atan2f(0, 0);
  else
   angleInRadians = atan2f(currentPoint.y - center.y, currentPoint.x - center.x) - atan2f(previousPoint.y - center.y, previousPoint.x - center.x);

Answer (score 0):

The limit of atan2 is pi, so when you reach the threshold of pi (horizontal on the left side of the circle), what is happening is your lastTouch is in the second quadrant really close to 180 degrees, and your current touch is in the third quadrant really close to -180 degrees. Read up here on atan2 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2.

According to your angleInRadians, 179.99 - (-179.99) = 359.98, or roughly 2pi, which is ~6.28. So when you hit that threshold, you are really adding close to 2pi, which is where the roughly 6.xxx is coming from.